# Variable scope in a nested for loop in c (cs50)

Tags: c, scope, cs50

In this code, where I'm applying a selection sort, why can't I use the variable i at the line that has the comment? Thanks

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (n-2); i++){
        int iSmallest = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < (n-1); j++){
            if(values[j] < values[iSmallest])/*Why can't I use values[i] instead of values[iSmallest]?*/
            iSmallest = j;
    }

    int temp = values[i];
    values[i] = values[iSmallest];
    values[iSmallest] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Who said you can't? there is a missing brace if I parse it correctly...

Comment: Did you try that ?

Comment: I've tried yes, but the sorting doesn't work if I change that. The missing brace is corrected in the original code. Everything works perfectly, but I don't understand why I can't use the variable i there instead of the variable iSmallest. It looks like i is out of scope there but I don't see why

Comment: So how have you fixed it? What do you men "Can't use"?

Comment: You say the missing brace is "corrected in the original code". Why does the code in your question differ from your "original code"? You need to copy-and-paste the *exact* code that's causing the problem into your question. We can't tell the difference between an error in your code and an error you made while re-typing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner loop, you need to keep track of the index of the smallest element you've found so far.

At the start of the inner loop, you take the index of the first element you look at, i.e. `i`, and initialize `iSmallest` with that.  When you find an element after that one which is smaller, you update `iSmallest` to the index of that element.

Then when you finish the inner loop, you use that index to swap the smallest element with the element at `i`.  That puts the smallest element at index `i`.  Then you increment `i` and repeat, finding the next smallest element.

The variable `i` is not out of scope in the line you commented on.  It's syntactically legal to have `if(values[j] < values[i])` at that line, but the sort won't work properly.

Comment: I am quite sure it is answering a completely different question.. Or this "can't use" is meaning something completely different from my understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dbush. But if it's syntactically legal to use values[i] at that line, and iSmallest = i, Why is the sort not working if I use values[i]?

Comment: Not all code that is syntactically legal is logically correct.

Comment: @JorgeLdg As the answer states, the value of `iSmallest` can change on each iteration of the inner loop.  So while it starts out containing the same value as `i`, it doesn't necessarily end that way.

Comment: Thanks @dbush. Now I understand :)